# ZF2 view rendering

Tags: zend-framework2

In ZF1 I can do something like this:

```
$view = new Zend_View();
$view->setScriptPath($viewDir);
$html = $view->render('template_name.phtml');
```

How can I do that in ZF2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public function abcAction()
{
    $view = new ViewModel(array('variable'=>$value));
    $view->setTemplate('module/controler/action.phtml'); // path to phtml file under view folder
    return $view;
}

 public function differentViewScriptAction()
    {
        // Use a different view script

        $viewModel = new ViewModel();
        $viewModel->setTemplate('application/view/arbitrary');
        return $viewModel;
    }
```

Thanks to [akrabat](http://zf2test.akrabat.com/) for covering almost every scenario.